# Why do I get StackOverflowError here?

Tags: java, generics, recursion, stack-overflow

Why does this java code produce `StackOverflowError`? I understand that this somehow connected with recursive generic type parameter. But I don't understand clear the whole mechanism.

```
public class SomeClass<T extends SomeClass> {

    SomeClass() {
        new SomeClassKiller();
    }

    private class SomeClassKiller extends SomeClass<T> {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the stack trace of the error? That should give you a clue about what's happening. It does not have anything to do with the type parameters - if you remove those, it still gives a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Good question on stackoverflow. (:

Comment: @Jesper: SomeClassKiller is being initialized infinite number of times. But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The generic part doesn't matter - nor does it really matter that the class is nested. Look at this mostly-equivalent pair of classes and it should be more obvious:

```
public class SuperClass
{
    public SuperClass()
    {
        new SubClass();
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    public SubClass()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

So the subclass constructor calls the superclass constructor - which then creates a new subclass, which calls into the superclass constructor, which creates a new subclass, etc... bang!

Comment: Hehe.. I was absolutely sure that the problem with generics and didn't notice this thing :)

Comment: `super();` is *almost* equivalent to `this = new SuperClass();`. Now it should be obvious...

Answer (score 2):

Here it is invoking one constructor from another and from it the previous one, cyclic constructor chain, see the comments below

```
public class SomeClass<T extends SomeClass> {

    SomeClass() {//A
        new SomeClassKiller();// calls B
    }

    private class SomeClassKiller extends SomeClass<T> {//B
               //calls A
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClass(); //calls A
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the **Recursive constructor calls** happening between the classes SomeClass and 
SomeClassKiller.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeClass<T extends SomeClass> {

    SomeClass() {
        new SomeClassKiller();
    }

    private class SomeClassKiller extends SomeClass<T> {
       public SomeClassKiller()
       {
         super(); //calls the constructor of SomeClass
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClass();
    }
}
```

The code produced by the compiler is something like this, so when u create an object it recursivly calls the SomeClass and SomeClassKiller for ever.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are invoked top-to-bottom, that is if a class `A` derives from `B`, A's constructors will first invoke the parent constructor (`B`).

In you case, `new SomeClassKiller()` recursively calls the constructor of `SomeClass` which in turn constructs another `SomeClassKiller` … there it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `main()` method is creating a new instance of `SomeClass` which calls the `SomeClass` **constructor** that creates a new instance of `SomeClassKiller` that by default calls the parent constructor and the stackoverflow occurs.

**To avoid the stackoverflow. Change the code to look as follows:**

```
public class SomeClass<T extends SomeClass> {

    SomeClass() {
        new SomeClassKiller();
    }

    private class SomeClassKiller extends SomeClass<T> {
        public SomeClassKiller(){
            //super(); does this by default, but is now commented out and won't be called.
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClass();
    }
}
```